# Low-rank factorization of a Finite Element matrix

Tags: matrices, factorization

I have a matrix $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, stemming from a Finite Element discretization of an advection function.

I want to find a factorization $ M= S E T $ with $S, T\in \mathbb R^{n\times s}$ and $E\in \mathbb R^{s\times s}$ with $s$ as small as possible.

I have two questions:

1. For example, one can do this by SVD, but which other general ways are there?
2. Can I use the special structure of the Finite Element discretization? Maybe one can use the repeating structure of the underlying conforming mesh....